# regex, force a digit to match \d and not \w or dot

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Good morning everyone,

Here is my issue: I have the file name test1.pdf and I want to check if the last character before .pdf is a digit. If it is, I want to extract it.
The following regex work:

```
(\D*)(\d?)(\.pdf)
```

I get my 3 elements: test/1/.pdf

But now my file is named test1test1.pdf. So I try this regex;

```
(\w*)(\d?)(\.pdf)
```

My regex isn't working anymore because I get: test1test1/.pdf instead of test1test/1/.pdf. So the last digit before the .pdf is included in (\w*)

This regex will solve this issue:

```
(\w*)(\d{1})(\.pdf)
```

But it won't work if there is no digit before the .pdf.
It won't match test1test.pdf for example.

I know some regex that will fix my problem but I find them not really elegant. Is there a way to force a digit to match \d rather than \w or dot, or is there a way to specify "end of parenthesis" like "end of string" with $?

Thank's for your help or tips
(btw I'm using PHP and the preg_match() function)

Comment: `\w*` => `\w*?`. Or, if the digit(s) before `.` is required, `(\w*?)(\d+)(\.pdf)`, or even `(.*?)(\d+)(\.pdf)`

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you. Indeed, the lazy/greedy distinction with ? was the solution to my issue